# Producing a custom activation function

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling, neural-networks, bayesian-network

I have two matrices of equal dimensions with values [0,1]. Basically two gray scale images which are predictions from a neural network. One matrix is the prediction output of a particular object given image $X$ and the second matrix is the prediction output of a different object (produced by a different network) given the same image $X$.

Now, each of the matrices has false positives that are actually true positives on the other matrix. For instance, matrix A, for location $(a,b)$ might give me a probability of $0.7$ that it is of class A and this might be a false positive. And in matrix B for that same location, the value might be probability of 0.4 for it being class B. Now, if that pixel was actually meant to be class B, just doing the $max(A,B)$ won't work.

So, I'd like to create some sort of activation function that will take these two matrices and produce another probability matrix as an output that combines the results. How do I go about does this? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Combining multiple classifiers to improve performance is normally called ensemble learning, if you look into that it might give you some ideas. Normally some kind of voting would be involved. You could chose max or if they are too close neither (as a ”don't know” option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each model needs to output not only their prediction, but for each class what their prediction is (of course summing to $1$).

Then, given two such models you can first average their predictions for each class and then choose the max.

E.g. model P produces probabilities:

```
A    B
0.7  0.3
```

and model Q produces probabilities:

```
A    B
0.1  0.9
```

Then their combined prediction is:

```
A    B
0.4  0.6
```

And B would be chosen.

Comment: But what if each model is binary and I want to combine these binary models. By binary, I mean, it only predicts if it's background or class A. Similarly, background or class B.

Comment: @Jonathan There is no proper way to combine such models to deal with 'false positives' - the best you can hope for is to choose the max probability, assuming you trust each model equally. If you trust one model more than the other you can weight probabilities.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you